# download only the new content in email reply by google gmail api

Tags: rest, google-api, gmail-api

I am trying to access Gmail messages via google API.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads

But the payload field returns the base64 of the body of the email. When an email is in a thread, it is usually to reply to a previous email. Therefore only the reply part is useful to show. The reply part can be shown by the GUI interface. Is there a way to get only the reply part via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no direct method of obtaining the last reply for each thread.

If you want to retrieve the last reply of the **email threads** you should first of all **retrieve all the messages** by using a `GET` request like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages
```

The request response will look something like this:

```
{
  "messages": [
    users.messages Resource
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "resultSizeEstimate": unsigned integer
}
```

Where the `users.messages` Resource looks something like this:

```
{
   "id": "",
   "threadId": ""
}
```

Having the `list` of all the `users.messages` Resources, the ones which contain the **same** `threadId` are the emails which in fact contain **replies**.

So in order to obtain the last reply, you could find which `threadId`s **appear more than once**, and then **retrieve the last occurrence of it** as it is the last reply. Or if you want all the replies (apart from the original email), you can retrieve all the occurrences apart from the first one (which is represented by the original email).

Lastly, to retrieve the message you can use a `GET` request like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id
```

**Note:** The `userId` is represented by the email address from which you want to retrieve the emails/replies and the `id` is represented by the `id` of the message.

**Reference**

- [Users.threads: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list);
- [Users.threads: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get);
- [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list);
- [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get).

Comment: I mean the reply part in each email. Not the reply email nor the last email of a thread. So, basically, there is no way to do so at least according to my read of the API. Is there a method to resolve the reply part locally (not via the API), once I download all the messages in a thread (prefer in python)? There are some python modules (e.g., https://github.com/zapier/email-reply-parser) that resolve the reply part in a per-message base, which should have a poorer performance compared to a method that can use info from the whole thread.

Comment: Hello, so let me understand more clearly - you want to get the **body** part of the reply email? Then why don't you use the `base64.urlsafe_b64decode` in order to decode it?

Comment: I want the reply part of the body. In other words, I want see what web version gmail normally show without expanding it.

Comment: So once you get the body - which is in base64 format - why don't you use `base64.urlsafe_b64decode ` to decode it? Cheers!

Comment: That is not the problem. The question is from the decoded body, how to tell what is reply what is quote, what is signature.

Comment: Hello @user1424739, what exactly do you mean by **reply**? The decoded body of a reply email is the reply itself. So if you want to extract only that and not the signatures you can easily do some string manipulation in order to find what you need. Cheers!